# inequality involving sum of two $p$th power integrable functions

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory

> Let $(S, \Omega, \mu)$ be a measure space. Prove that for two $p$th power integrable functions $f$ and $g$ on $S,$
> $$\|f+g\|_p^p \leq 2^{p-1} (\|f\|_p^p + \|g\|_p^p), \text{ where } \|f\|_p := \left( \int_S |f|^p \,d\mu\right)^{1/p}.$$

I know that
\begin{align}
\|f+g\|_p^p & = \int_S |f+g|^p \, d\mu \\[8pt]
& \leq \int_S (2\max \{|f|, |g|\})^p \, d\mu \\[8pt]
& = 2^p\int_S (\max\{|f|, |g|\})^p d\mu,
\end{align}
where $\max\{|f|, |g|\}(x)$ for any $x\in S$ is defined to be $\max\{|f(x)|,|g(x)|\}.$ How do I get the $2^{p-1}$ value? I know that $\int_S (\max\{|f|, |g|\})^p d\mu \leq \int_S |f|^p \, d\mu + \int_S |g|^p \, d\mu,$ so perhaps I need a stronger inequality? Or maybe I should use the convexity of the function $t\mapsto t^p$ for $p\geq 1$ which states that $(sx + (1-s)y)^p \leq sx^p + (1-s)y^p$ for any $s\in [0,1]\text{?}$

Answer (score 1):

Indeed convexity of $|x|^p$ for $p>1$ salvages this:

$$|f+g|^p=2^p|\frac{1}{2}f+\frac{1}{2}g|^p\leq 2^{p-1}(|f|^p+|g|^p). $$